# Kibana web interface not loading

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, kibana, kibana-4

Despite ElasticSearch and Kibana both running on my production server, I'm unable to visit the GUI over the public IP: http://52.4.153.19:5601/

Localhost curls return 200 but console errors on the browser report timeouts after a few images are retrieved.

I've successfully installed, run, and accessed Kibana on my local (Windows 10) and on my staging AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 environment.  I'm able to access both over port 5601 on localhost and the staging environment is accessible over the public IP address and all domains addressed accordingly.  The reverse proxy also works and all status indicators are green on the dashboard.

I'm running Kibana 4.5, ElasticSearch 2.3.1, Apache 2.4.12

I've used the same exact volume from the working environment to attach to the production instance, so everything is identical on the two volumes, except that the staging environment's apache vhost uses a subdomain while the production environment's servername is the base domain.  Both are configured for SSL wildcards.  Both are in separate availability zones at Amazon.  I've tried altering the server block to use a subdomain on the production server, just to see if the domain was impactful but the error remains.

I also tried running one instance individually, in case EC2 had some kind of networking error with 0.0.0.0 but I'm unable to come to a resolution.  All logs and configurations are identical between the two servers for ElasticSearch and Kibana.

I've tried deleting and re-creating the kibana index, tried alternate settings inclusive of the host, elasticsearch url, extending the max ping and timeout, max retries, extended the apache limits, http.cors to allow different origins.  I've tried other ports but both servers are indicating that 5601 is listening in the same way.

I also had the same problem on a completely different volume that was previously attached to this instance.

The only difference I can see is that the working version pings fine while the non-working version has a 100% packet loss when pinging the IP, although I can't imagine why that would be, as I'm able to reach the website on 80, just fine.  I can also access various other tools running on other ports.  I assume there might be some kind of networking conflict.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you make sure that on staging server port 5601 is accessible from public IP, can you check your firewall rules once again to verify? Timeouts mainly happen when the request does not reaches the required server and no body is there to respond back.

Comment: The staging server isn't a problem. To be clear, when I say I've 'accessed kibana', I'm doing it on the public IP at 5601.  Every port that's opened and accessible on staging is also open and accessible on live (22, 80, 443, 10000, etc) from public IP's and domains. Only 5601 on live fails but both servers have identical iptables. Even if I try to bind kibana or elasticsearch to non-standard ports, I still get the same issue.

Comment: Have you binded Ip too for kibana?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't be able to start it successfully and have it running on 5601 if it wasn't binded.

Comment: Given that the dev server instance ran without an error with an identical volume, I had a feeling there's some networking conflict at AWS with this particular instance.  I spun up a new live instance as a clone of the live server that wasn't working and it immediately worked.  I can't quite explain it but if I just trash the work that doesn't work, that'll at least get me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, forgot to update this question.  The answer turned out being that I simply needed to deploy a new instance.  Simply by creating a clone of the instance, I was able to resolve the issue.  I've had networking problems at AWS, before, with their internal dns/ip conflicts, so I've had to do so, in the past and this turned out to be the quickest and cleanest solution, albeit not providing any definitive insight into the cause.

Answer (score 0):

May be port `5601` is blocked by firewall

Allow incoming connections to port 5601 by:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5601 -j ACCESS
```

For security:

Modify above mentioned command and accept connection only from specific address. (See `man iptables`)

or use **Shield** plugin for elasticseach

Comment: Port 5601 is not blocked. That rule was already set up (accept, not access). Both servers have identical iptables and netstat is showing the same listening results for both. Also as indicated, the logs are showing the same results as the healthy server. Kibana verbose shows connection to Elasticsearch, too. I can make ElasticSearch calls on both servers remotely from my web services over port 80 and 443.  I'll give shield a shot but how will that address this issue if it isn't needed on the other server?

Comment: Given that the dev server instance ran without an error with an identical volume, I had a feeling there's some networking conflict at AWS with this particular instance.  I spun up a new live instance as a clone of the live server that wasn't working and it immediately worked.  I can't quite explain it but if I just trash the work that doesn't work, that'll at least get me through this.